# Django, context dict not passing through to template? (for loop returns nothing)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I did a search for this but couldn't find anything, so here it is..

My views are set up like this, the status.html for loop works fine but the tasks.html doesn't register my for loop at all, and I don't see what I'm doing wrong when comparing the 2 view functions/templates.

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from todo.models import List, Item

# Create your views here.

def current_tasks(request):
    tasks = List.objects.all()
    tasks_dict = {'tasks': tasks}

    return render(request, 'tasks.html', tasks_dict)

def status_report(request):
    todo_listing = []

    for todo_list in List.objects.all():
        todo_dict = {}

        todo_dict['list_object'] = todo_list
        todo_dict['item_count'] = todo_list.item_set.count()
        todo_dict['items_complete'] = todo_list.item_set.filter(completed=True).count()
        todo_dict['percent_complete'] = int(float(todo_dict['items_complete']) / todo_dict['item_count'] * 100)

        todo_listing.append(todo_dict)

    return render(request, 'status.html', {'todo_listing': todo_listing})
```

tasks.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% for tasks in tasks_dict %}
        <ul><li>{{tasks.title}}</li><
        <li>{{tasks.created_date}}</li>
        <li>{{tasks.priority}}</li>
        <li>{{tasks.completed}}</li></ul>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

status.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Task List Status Report</h1>
{% for list_dict in todo_listing %}
    <h2>{{ list_dict.list_object.title }}</h2>

    <ul>
        <li>Number of items: {{ list_dict.item_count }}</li>
        <li>Number completed: {{ list_dict.items_complete }} ({{ list_dict.percent_complete }}%)</li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending anything called `tasks_dict` to your template; that's just the local name of your context dictionary. The thing you're sending to the template that contains tasks is called just `tasks`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I know that came across as a stupid question but I didn't realize I wasn't passing the dictionary to the template.